# Q: Abstract class object initiation code?

Tags: java, abstract-class

**In this class abstract class object is instantiated by overriding the getNum(), what is the purpose of this?**

```
public abstract class AbstractTest {
 public int getNum() {
  return 45;
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) // main function
  {
   AbstractTest t = new AbstractTest() // From this point didn't understand
    {
     public int getNum() // function
      {
       return 22;
      }
    }; //use of this        
   System.out.println(t.getNum()); // output
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instantiation in your `main()` method is simply an inline class definition of a concrete instance of the abstract class `AbstractTest`.  To be clear, the variable `t` is an anonymous, non abstract class instance.  The following code would achieve the same thing:

```
public class ConcreteTest extends AbstractTest {
    @Override
    public int getNum() {
        return 22;
    }
}

public static void main (String [] args) {
    ConcreteTest t = new ConcreteTest();
    System.out.println(t.getNum());
}
```

There are instances in the course of development where it can be cumbersome to have to create a formal class definition.  For example, if you only need a single instance of the abstract `AbstractTest` class, it would be easier to use an inline definition.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but what do you mean by **concrete instance of the abstract class AbstractTest**.

Comment: By "concrete" I mean not `abstract`, i.e. an actual instance of a class which extends the abstract class from your sample code.

Answer (score 0):

We call this 'Anonymous Class': When you need to create and use a class, but do not need to give its name or reused use, you can use an anonymous class. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) is the offical doc. Not only used for abstract class, can also be used for interface and general extensible class.

```
interface Base {
    void print();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Base aInterface = new Base() {
        @Override
        public void print() {
            System.out.println("A anonymous implement.");
        }
    };

    Thread aThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
        }
    };
}
```